# Storing vim macro - how to store a move-to-next-line operation?

Tags: vim, macros

I want to store a macro that inserts a symbol at the beginning of a line and then moves to the next line (such that I can call multiple of them)

I made a recording of what I want and then used ctrl R ctrl R to paste it directly into my vimrc where it came out as;

```
  nmap @c I%<80>kd^[
```

The problem is when I then call it, "%<80>kd" gets inserted, instead of just the "%" symbol.

----More info:
As you can probably guess I'm trying to insert comments, I'd also like to remove them with a similar @x invocation.  I want to be able to call this on whatever number of lines so it needs to finish with a move-to-next-line operation.  I know about the alternative approach of using visual mode and I% esc esc, but I find this easier - I used to have it working but have lost my vimrc and now don't seem to be able to re-create it alas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `.vimrc`.

To insert `%` in the begining of each line & move to next line:

```
let @c="I%\<esc>+"
```

To delete first character from the beginning of each line & move to next line

```
let @d="0x+"
```

Comment: You can use key notation if you use double quotes and escape. e.g. `let @c="I%\<esc>+"`

Answer (score 0):

`nmap @c I%<ESC>j` seems to work for me. I am able to paste that using `"cp` (paste from register `c`).

To delete the first character, `nmap @d ^xj`.